# apt-get keeps failing

Tags: linux-mint, apt

Similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633672/ubuntu-14-04-cannot-update), I cannot `apt-get update` my machine.

I've tried everything I could Google: adding the bad key, deleting my `/var/lists/thingy`, `apt-get clean`, deleting Chrome.

But I keep getting the error below. Is there a more nuclear option?  Like deleting the update manager and redownloading it or something?

```
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_ZA                
Fetched 23,8 MB in 1min 41s (234 kB/s)                                         
W: GPG error: http://packages.linuxmint.com rosa Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 3EE67F3D0FF405B2 Clement Lefebvre (Linux Mint Package Repository v1) <root@linuxmint.com>
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: Failed to fetch http://extra.linuxmint.com/dists/rosa/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
```

**Update:**

I've tried this:

- removing google chrome
- adding keys: `sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 3EE67F3D0FF405B2`

-

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

- and everything in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

**Update 2**

- apt-key list

  pub   1024D/437D05B5 2004-09-12
  uid                  Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key 
  sub   2048g/79164387 2004-09-12

  pub   1024D/FBB75451 2004-12-30
  uid                  Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key

  pub   4096R/C0B21F32 2012-05-11
  uid                  Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012)

  pub   4096R/EFE21092 2012-05-11
  uid                  Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012)

  pub   1024D/0FF405B2 2009-04-29
  uid                  Clement Lefebvre (Linux Mint Package Repository v1) 
  sub   2048g/0F346519 2009-04-29

  pub   1024D/3E5C1192 2010-09-20
  uid                  Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key

  pub   4096R/46D7E7CF 2009-05-15
  uid                  GetDeb Archive Automatic Signing Key

  pub   4096R/2C52609D 2015-07-14
  uid                  Docker Release Tool (releasedocker)

  pub   1024R/28949509 2010-08-22
  uid                  Launchpad Gwendal Le Bihan

  pub   1024D/7FAC5991 2007-03-08
  uid                  Google, Inc. Linux Package Signing Key 
  sub   2048g/C07CB649 2007-03-08

  pub   4096R/D38B4796 2016-04-12
  uid                  Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) 
  sub   4096R/640DB551 2016-04-12 [expires: 2019-04-1
- apt-cache policy

  Package files:
   100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
       release a=now
  Pinned packages:

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the commands you tried. *How* exactly did you add *what* key? What was the output of whatever command you used to add it? What is `/var/lists/thingy`?

Comment: Please paste the output of `apt-cache policy` into the question. Also, the output of `apt-key list`.

Comment: The "Hash Sum mismatch" error is typically gotten rid of by deleting the corresponding file from `/var/lib/apt/lists`. It would start with `extra.linuxmint.com_dists_rosa...` The GPG errors don't actually cause anything to fail, afaik.

Comment: Same problem discussed : https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=217501

Comment: Could you try running `sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::http::No-Cache=True` to make sure it is not a server side problem? This is basically what was done to resolve the problem in the thread linked by @SeverusTux

Comment: I ran that command. Didn't see any errors.

Comment: You have the answer here :http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey. There is the same problem

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think Mint works the same way as Ubuntu. When I try running that answer's code I get: 
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 y-ppa-manager : Depends: xterm but it is not installable
                 Depends: python-launchpadlib but it is not installable
E: Unable

Comment: your errors show the long key id and your dump shows the short key id... so they cannot be compared. Use `apt-key finger` for more detail, and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Without more info, all I can suggest is:

Try installing another copy of the same OS release, updating it (apt-get update, upgrade, and dist-upgrade), and then copying the suspected relevant parts of it to the broken machine (after making backups of course). For example copy /etc/apt/ and /var/lib/apt/ and see if apt-get update will work then.

Comment: Yeah, I'm giving up. The link @jschlichtolz shared basically says there's no solution. I'll switch to Ubuntu as they have an entire StackExchange forum for support for stuff like this.  Though I'll miss Cinnamon.

Comment: @Richard if you think it's just Mint that's broken and only use it for Cinnamon, then just install Cinnamon on another distro...

Comment: Although theoretically that should work people in other forums complain about compatibility issues. The problem with Linux is there're always weird little errors. So I think it would be better to just stick to Ubuntu standard - easier for support.

Comment: I once had a similar error that had to do with my corporate proxy/webfilter blocking specific downloads (while allowing browsing the directories). try accessing/ downloading the URLs directly through a web browser or curl and see how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command for the GPG error : 
`sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 3EE67F3D0FF405B2 40976EAF437D05B5`. 
Then for the Hash Sum mismatch try running these commands : `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Thanks, I've done that. It was listed in the link in my question I think

Comment: In that case i see 3 options that you can do : 1. No longer use apt-get :use aptitude. 2.reinstall apt-get `aptitude purge apt-get ` and `aptitude install apt-get` 3. Like in the Peter's answer , reinstall the OS.

Comment: I tried these commands trying to understand what you said above, but got the same error at the end: 1) sudo apt-get install aptitude 2) sudo aptitude purge apt-get 3) sudo aptitude install apt-get 4) apt-get update